# bada Programming - Call listview within a listview

Tags: c++, listview, bada

I currently have a listview containing 4 items, in one of the listview item, I would like to implement another listview, do I have to do another form manager? Or how do I go about doing it? Also, how do I call one class's function in another class? Or do a reference (pointer) to pass information from one class to another?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question 100%.

In short, you would need pointer from one list view to another. If you are in a form then a local pointer to the list view may suffice.

Same applies with referencing class instances:

```
class Apple() {
  private Basket* basket;
  public Apple() { 
    basket = null;
  }
  public void setBasket(Basket* basket) {
    this->basket = basket;
  }
  public Basket* getBasket() {
    return this->basket;
  }
}

class Basket() {
  private Apple* apple;
  public Basket() {
    apple = null;
  }
  public setApple(Apple* apple) {
    this->apple = apple;
    this->apple->setBasket(this);
  }
}

...
Apple* apple = new Apple();
Basket* basket = new Basket()
basket->setApple(apple);
```

Hope it helps a little.

Okay I am adding more code here to see if it helps **It is not tested, written on the fly to show the principal**:

FormA.h

```
class FormA : 
    public Osp::Ui::Controls::Form, 
    public Osp::Ui::IItemEventListener 
{

    // Other stuff including list
protected:
  void  OnItemStateChanged (const Osp::Ui::Control &source, int index, int itemId, Osp::Ui::ItemStatus status);   
}
```

FormA.cpp

```
    // Other stuff including constructor and list control creation/population

void FormA::OnItemStateChanged (const Osp::Ui::Control &source, int index, int itemId, Osp::Ui::ItemStatus status) {

  // Construct and show other form
  FormB* b = new FormB(itemId);
  // Add to frame and set formb as current

}
```

FormB.h

```
class FormA : 
    public Osp::Ui::Controls::Form, 
    public Osp::Ui::IItemEventListener 
{
private int itemId;
public:
  FormA(int itemId);  
}
```

FormB.cpp

```
FormA::FormA(int itemId) {
 this->itemId = itemId;
}

// Now somewhere in your form initialization read the itemId
// value (this->itemId) and decide what you want to show in the form's list view
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond! I think you understand me. I have a listview currently. When the user clicks on one of the item, it should get the elementID and pass the elementID to the 2nd form so that it knows what to display in the 2nd form. I really have no idea how to do this. I do not know what is needed to be included in the .h and .cpp file. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, glad I understood the question. An answer could be to create a function that populates the 2nd list view when something is selected on the first one. If this function is on the same form were both views reside then I don't see any scoping issues as both list views should have pointers somewhere in the private section. If the view is in another form all together then I would guess you only need to pass the id of the element selected to the second view to fetch the records... sorry but not an easy answer to describe here without having the space for lines and lines of code :)

Comment: As in, create a function that populates the 2nd form in the 1st form? Oh man, I'm so lost at this :(

Comment: Hi there, I did exactly what you've said but I get this on my FormA no matching function for call to 'FormB::FormB(int&)' Btw, I have to include FormA.h in FormB and vice versa, right?

Comment: Sorry buddy but your questions are C++ basics and not Bada. As much as I would like to help the content is way to much to get into. In short you yes you need to include formb.h to be able to compile... but that is only a hint.